# how to upload one file many times into folder

Tags: c#, asp.net, file-upload

I want to upload one file many times into folder. Here my code...

```
foreach (HttpPostedFile postedFile in FileUpload1.PostedFiles)
{
    string filename = Path.GetFileName(postedFile.FileName);
    string FileExtension = Path.GetExtension(postedFile.FileName);
    for(int i = 1; i <= data.Count;i++)
    {
        FileUpload1.PostedFile.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/InvoiceUploads/") + "Invoice " 
        + id + "_" + i + FileExtension);
    }
}
```

this code was to upload one file many times, but the problem is that only one file can open perfectly and the other is given an error and it says empty file.
what's the problem that I don't know?
please anybody help me.

Thank You.

Comment: `SaveAs()` probably leaves the stream at its end. Use `File.Copy()` instead, or reset the stream if possible (which it probably isn't).

Comment: Tested your snippet with an image, and it works fine! All the images are readable.

Comment: Thanks but, Still same. @CodeCaster

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
void SendFile()
{
   foreach (HttpPostedFile postedFile in FileUpload1.PostedFiles)
   {
      string filename = Path.GetFileName(postedFile.FileName);
      string FileExtension = Path.GetExtension(postedFile.FileName);

      // Add a delay
      Thread.Sleep(100);

      for(int i = 1; i <= data.Count;i++){
        postedFile.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/InvoiceUploads/") + "Invoice " + id + "_" + i + FileExtension);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Thank You very much, So helpful to me.
Thanks once again.

Answer (score 0):

why `FileUpload1.PostedFile.SaveAs`? Use `HttpPostedFile .SaveAs(...)` instead.

```
foreach (HttpPostedFile postedFile in FileUpload1.PostedFiles)
{
string filename = Path.GetFileName(postedFile.FileName);
string FileExtension = Path.GetExtension(postedFile.FileName);
for(int i = 1; i <= data.Count;i++){
     postedFile .SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/InvoiceUploads/") + "Invoice " + id + "_" + i + FileExtension);
}
}
```

Comment: sorry, still same.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Need to Change code

```
foreach (HttpPostedFile postedFile in FileUpload1.PostedFiles)
      {
        string filename = Path.GetFileName(postedFile.FileName);
        string FileExtension = Path.GetExtension(postedFile.FileName);
        string CurrDate = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy_MM_dd_HH_mm_ss");

        for(int i = 1; i <= data.Count;i++)
           {
             FileUpload1.PostedFile.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/InvoiceUploads/") + 
             "Invoice " 
              + id + "_" + i + CurrDate + FileExtension);
           }
      }
```